# How to create a telegram sticker package using an API?

Tags: telegram

I want to add a sticker package from software to Telegram. I do not know how to do this. How can I do this using an API?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the [@Stickers](https://t.me/Stickers) bot or https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#stickers

Comment: The @Stickers bot does do the job but the bot api you provided simply describe the specification of stickers, but not how to create a sticker.